# Groovy switch not behaving as expected

Tags: groovy

I've got the test.groovy script below, but when I run it, I get the following output.

```
groovy test.groovy
set color to good
set color to unstable
unstable
```

Why am I seeing 'set color to good'?

Line 13 states

```
case "SUCCESS" :
```

But buildStatus is "UNSTABLE"

I've never used a switch statement before in groovy, so could be missing something pretty basic.

test.groovy

```
def print_arg(def arg){
    buildStatus = "UNSTABLE"
    previousBuild = "FAILURE"
    // println "$arg"
    switch(buildStatus) {
        case { it != "SUCCESS" } :
            switch(previousBuild) {
                case "SUCCESS" :
                    println "set color to danger"
                    color = 'danger'
                    break;
            }
        case "SUCCESS" :
            switch(previousBuild) {
                case { it != "SUCCESS"} :
                    println "set color to good"
                    color = 'good'
                    break;
            }
        case "UNSTABLE" :
            println "set color to unstable"
            color = 'unstable'
            break;
    }
println "$color"
}

print_arg()
```

Comment: As the answer says, you need `break;` statements to avoid fall-through, but even after you've done that, notice that your last case ("UNSTABLE") will *never* be executed because you'll get the first case instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I've given up on nested switch case statements now, the if else code I was trying to replicate is shorter and more readable!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see `set color to good` because you don't have a `break` statement at the end of your 1st case.

The 1st case matches with `{ it != "SUCCESS" }`, the nested switch does not. Then the excecution proceeds to the 2nd case due to the lack of `break` before. The 2nd case executes and also doesn't have a `break`, so it falls through to the 3rd case.

So, the `switch` operates exactly how it supposed to.

I'm not sure what your original intention was and having nested `switch` ops does not increase the readability of your code, but I'd put your code like that:

```
    switch(buildStatus) {
        case { it != "SUCCESS" } :
            switch(previousBuild) {
                case "SUCCESS" :
                    println "set color to danger"
                    color = 'danger'
                    break;
            }
            break // << ADD THIS
        case "SUCCESS" :
            switch(previousBuild) {
                case { it != "SUCCESS"} :
                    println "set color to good"
                    color = 'good'
                    break;
            }
            break // << ADD THIS
        case "UNSTABLE" :
            println "set color to unstable"
            color = 'unstable'
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks injecteer.  I'm going back to if else statements as it's much more readable than this nested switch ops, and less code!